# Conditionally format the first cell in a column that matches criteria

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, count, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I would like to conditionally format the first instance in a column where the value matches the criteria (in the example below >= 1000000).

Here is an example spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bz2jHn_rQneb62QLuSGv46PdOv7V5SennmeL3vQcPbo/edit#gid=0

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=(INDEX(COUNTIFS(IF(A$2:A>=1000000, 1), IF(A2>=1000000, 1), 
  ROW(A$2:A), "<="&ROW(A2)))=1)*(A2>=1000000)
```

[image]